# Symfony2 - Accessing bundle parameters from a service

Tags: symfony

How do I inject one of my bundle configuration parameters into a service?

When I have a service like this:

```
<!-- My Object FormType -->
<service id="form.type.my_object" class="My\Bundle\Form\Type\MyObjectType">
  <tag name="form.type" alias="my_object"/>
  <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager"/>
  <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
  <argument type="string">%my_bundle.some_parameter%</argument>
</service>
```

And I have put the parameter in config.yml:

```
my_bundle:
    some_parameter: My\Bundle\Entity\SomeEntityClass
```

I am getting this error:

```
The service "form.type.my_object" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "my_bundle.some_parameter".
```

How do I solve this (without having the bundle parameter listed in the global application parameters)  ?

**EDIT**

I am looking for a way without using parameters.yml.

**UPDATE**

This is how my config is loaded:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();

    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
    $container->setParameter('my_bundle.config', $config);

    $loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));

    $serviceFiles = array('form', 'services');

    foreach ($serviceFiles as $basename) {
        $loader->load(sprintf('%s.xml', $basename));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to have a bundle configuration in config.yml you'll need to handle this in your bundle's [`%your-bundle%\DependencyInjection\Configuration`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html) class.

Comment: @Yoshi: thanks and yes I have done that, see updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Define your parameter in "parameters.yml"

```
parameters:
    my_bundle:
         some_parameter: My\Bundle\Entity\SomeEntityClass
```

and access it in your service using: %my_bundle.some_parameter%

Comment: This could be done even with DependencyInjection and Contaneir, you should specify it

Comment: as per the last part of my question, I am looking for a way to go without global parameters / parameters.yml

Answer (score 0):

Probably your bundle parameter file is not loaded by your bundle.

If, for example, you defined your parameters in your `parameters.yml` in your `MyBundle/Resources/Config` folder, your bundle extension class `MyBundle/DependencyInjection/MyBundleExtension` should contain:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
        $container,
        new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config')
    );
    $loader->load('parameters.yml');
}
```

**EDIT**

Another solution. Just add a line in your global config.yml file with

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: @MyBundle/Resources/config/parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Turns out you can do it very easily in the following way:

```
// My\VendorBundle\DependencyInjection\MyBundleExtension.php
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();

    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
    $container->setParameter('my_bundle.config', $config);

    $loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));

    $this->setBundleParameters($container,$config);

    $serviceFiles = array('form', 'services');

    foreach ($serviceFiles as $basename) {
        $loader->load(sprintf('%s.xml', $basename));
    }
}

/**
 * @param ContainerBuilder $container
 * @param $config
 * @return $this
 */
private function setBundleParameters(ContainerBuilder $container, $config)
{
    $container->setParameter('my_bundle.some_parameter', $config['some_parameter']);

    return $this;
}
```

Now that I am looking at it, probably I could also have used this as an argument:

```
<!-- My Object FormType -->
<service id="form.type.my_object" class="My\Bundle\Form\Type\MyObjectType">
  ...
  <argument type="string">%my_bundle.config.some_parameter%</argument>
</service>
```